# Can we solve the following integral by MATHEMATICA?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, scripting, code

I am trying to solve the integral using the following Mathematica code.

`f1 = (t[m + 1] - t)^(\[Alpha] - 1)*(t - t[m - 1])*(t - t[m - 2]);`

`Integrate[f1, {t, t[k], t[k + 1]}]`

But it doesn't work. Can you guys please help me solve it using Mathematica? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Perhaps `Integrate[f1,{t,t[k],t[k+1]},GenerateConditions->False]` does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
f1[s_] := (t[m + 1] - s)^(\[Alpha] - 1) (s - t[m - 1]) (s - t[m - 2]);
Integrate[f1[s], {s, t[k], t[k + 1]}, Assumptions -> {\[Alpha], t[k], t[k + 1], t[m - 1], t[m - 2], 
t[m + 1]} \[Element] Reals]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1/(\[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]) (2 + \[Alpha])) (I +  Cot[\[Pi] \[Alpha]]) Sin[\[Pi] \[Alpha]] ((1 + \[Alpha]) (2 + \ \[Alpha]) t[-2 + m] t[-1 +  m] ((t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - (t[1 + k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha]) + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]) t[ k]^2 (t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]) t[ 1 + k]^2 (t[1 + k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] +  2 \[Alpha] t[k] (t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] t[1 + m] -  2 \[Alpha] t[1 + k] (t[1 + k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] t[1 + m] +  2 ((t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - (t[1 + k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha]) t[1 + m]^2 - (2 + \[Alpha]) t[-2 +  m] (\[Alpha] t[k] (t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - \[Alpha] t[1 + k] (t[1 + k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] + ((t[k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - (t[1 + k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha]) t[ 1 + m]) - (2 + \[Alpha]) t[-1 +  m] (\[Alpha] t[k] (t[k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - \[Alpha] t[ 1 + k] (t[1 + k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] + ((t[k] -  t[1 + m])^\[Alpha] - (t[1 + k] - t[1 + m])^\[Alpha]) t[ 1 + m])),  t[k] > 0 && t[1 + k] > t[k] && 0 < t[1 + m] < t[k]]`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comment, it is `GenerateConditions` which sometimes makes it slow. To verify this, do the definite integration by hand and verify it is same as when turning this condition checking off. Sometimes I think the default for `GenerateConditions` should have been `False` and the user should set it to `True` if they want. Now it is the other way around.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1 = (t[m + 1] - t)^(α - 1)*(t - t[m - 1])*(t - t[m - 2]);
sol = Integrate[f1, t];
upper = Limit[sol, t -> t[k + 1]];
lower = Limit[sol, t -> t[k]];
sol1 = (upper - lower)

sol2 = Integrate[f1, {t, t[k], t[k + 1]}, GenerateConditions -> False]

Simplify[sol1 - sol2]

(* 0 *)
```

The solution is

[image: Mathematica graphics]